# Pass props to component wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobx-react

I have a higher order component that switches between two children (component that renders data and loading component):
,the issue is how to pass the loading state that happens in the data component to the hoc in order to do the conditional rendering

**Wrapper:**

```
function withLoading<Props>(DataComponent: React.FC<Props>, LoadingComponent: React.FC<Partial<Props>>) {
  const newComponent: React.FC<Props & { isLoading: boolean }> = (props) => {
    const {
      isLoading,
    } = props;
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <LoadingComponent
          {...props}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <DataComponent
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
  return newComponent;
}
```

**Data and loading components:**

```
const DataComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {

  const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    //Loading Logic happens in this mobx store
    await getDataFromBackend();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getBranchName();
  }, []);

return (
  //UI
)

const LoadingComponent = () => {
  const {
    selectStyle,
  } = useStyles(styles);
  return (
    <SkeletonPlaceholderWrapper>
      <View style={styles.loader} />
    </SkeletonPlaceholderWrapper>
  );
};

export default observer(
    withLoading(observer(DataComponent), LoadingComponent) //here the hoc wrapping the two children
  ),
```

Comment: `withLoading(observer(DataComponent), LoadingComponent)(store.isLoading)` pass loading state here, from your mobx

Answer (score 1):

In the wrapper change this :

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(isLoading)
```

Change the `if(isLoading)` to `if(loading)`

Pass the function setLoading as props to DataComponent

```
<DataComponent onComplete = {() => setLoading(false)} />
```

In the DataComponent, update your `fetchData` method :

```
const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    //Loading Logic happens in this mobx store
    await getDataFromBackend();
    props.onComplete() //<--- add this line
};
```